# To test whether a process is a Martingale (Stochastic calculus)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

If $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, I was trying to prove $Y_t = \exp (\int_{0}^{t} s\cdot dW_s)$ is a martingale ! First I started finding $dY_t$ using Ito formula. But I am confused how to calculate partial differentials of $Y_t$ with respect to $t$ and $W_t$. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated !

Comment: Why do you believe it is a martingale? Do you know the distribution of $\int_0^t s d W_s $? Have you heard of characteristic functions?

Comment: Also try to at least provide anything you tried to solve the problem. How would you start? Which condition does $Y_t$ have to satisfy in order to be a martingale?